# Java's ExecutorService.awaitTermination vs Future.get(<TimeOut>)

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using ExecutorService and submitting 2 Callables.

Can you tell me what is the difference between using ExecutorService.awaitTermination vs using the Future.get() ?

I do not want the threads to keep running indefinitely, and also each Future's exception should not affect other thread's Future.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Future<MyObject1> obj1 = null;
    if (true) { 
        task1 = executor.submit(<Callable1>);
    }

    Future<MyObject2> obj2 = null;
    if (<Condition>) {
        task2 = executor.submit(<Callable2>);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(TIMEOUT_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }finally {
        if( !executor.isTerminated()) {

        }

        try {
            executor.shutdownNow(); 
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }

    }


    MyObject1 myobj1 = null;

    try {
        myobj1 = task1 != null ? task1.get() : null;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {

    } 

    MyObject2 myobj2 = null;

    try {
        myobj2 = task2 != null ? task2.get() : null;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    }
```

Comment: What does 'threads to be canceled' mean? Can you write up your use cases as specific code examples?

Comment: Basically, i do not want them to keep running indefinitely, so they need to be interrupted. I edited my question. let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. One of these is about waiting for the completion of an individual task. The other is about closing down the entire executor altogether.

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to provide awaitTerminator for ExecutorService then ? Why would someone then provide individual timeout's in Future.get ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'provide'? Can you edit your question with the specifics of what you're trying to do, and again, preferably with some code?

Comment: I edited my question to provide sample code. As you can see i am using Timeout in awaitTermination of ExecutorService. Is there a benefit of using Future.get(<TimeOut>) ?

Comment: Your code isn't valid java code so it's hard to say anything about it. The distinction is pretty simple - `Future` represents some asynchronous task that returns a result. By calling `get` you're asking for that result and the timeout specifies how long you are willing to wait to to receive that result. `awaitTermination` on `ExecutorService` is a way for you to wait for _all_ tasks handled by that service to complete. The timeout is, again, how long you're willing to wait. You are not getting the results for specific tasks at all, you're simply waiting for everything to be done.

Comment: Future.get() blocks until thread complete its execution. ExecutorService.awaitTermination tries to shutdown the thread pool in a given time, blocking the code execution. To shutdown a thread pool, all threads must be terminated.

Comment: @Josh somewhat pedantically, neither `Future` nor `ExecutorService` really say anything about threads or pools of them. Just about synchronous vs asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: @avojak : I do not need the ExecutorService afterwards. Why is it not good to call shutdown() and do awaitTermination() ?

Comment: @NoviceUser It's fine if you don't care what happens to the potential results of your tasks. But that's not what you asked, you asked if `Future.get` and `awaitTermination` are different. They are very different.

Answer (score 4):

**Similarity** between `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` and `Future.get(<TimeOut>)` is that both are blocking in nature. Suppose you have called any of these methods in thread `T` then `T` will be blocked until condition associated with each is fulfilled.

In case of `ExecutorService.awaitTermination`, thread will be blocked until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first. Read [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). While in case of `Future.get(<TimeOut>)` thread will be blocked until the task is submitted and result is returned or an exception occured etc. Read [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()).

**Difference** between them is "usability" of each and key driver for that is as mentioned below:

**`ExecutorService.awaitTermination`**

- Should be use when you want to block the thread and do wish to proceed further until a specified time is elapsed (that is the time you will specify in `awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`) Typically people either specify value like `Long.MAX_VALUE` so as to wait too long or smaller values which they think as per their business requirement, for example if I am waiting for response to be committed to GUI then I may not wait more than 5 minutes.
- Should be used when you do not care about the results returned by the threads executing tasks.
- Should be used when you do not want to wait infinitely for tasks to finish, and want to specify some threshold time.

**`Future.get(<TimeOut>)`**

- Key difference between this and later is that you should use it when you want the thread to return the results and until that happens you want to keep the thread blocked and do not want to proceed further, and that's the reason you will use `Callable` when submitting the tasks. So, when you call `Future.get(<TimeOut>)` then thread will be blocked until results are returned by the thread or some exception occurs in the executing thread.

---

Refer below sample code I have created to demonstrate the usability of each, I have provided inline code comments to better explanation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        testFutureGet(); // after testing comment out this and uncomment below
        //testAwaitTermination();
    }

    private static void testAwaitTermination() throws InterruptedException {
List<Future<String>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();

        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask1 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(2000, true);
        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask2 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(1000, true);
        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask3 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(3000, true);

        System.out.println("### Starting submitting tasks");

        // submit the callable and register the returned future object so that it can be processed later.
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask1));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask2));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask3));

        executorService.shutdown();

        System.out.println("### Finished submitting tasks and shutdown executorService " + new Date());

        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // try this with 10 seconds and you will see after 3 seconds it reaches next line

        // uncomment below and comment out above.
        /*new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("@@@" + new Date());
                    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // try this with 10 seconds and you will see after 3 seconds it reaches next line
                    System.out.println("@@@" + new Date());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };
        }.start();*/

        System.out.println("### Finished. " + new Date());
    }

    private static void testFutureGet() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<Future<String>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask1 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(2000, false);
        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask2 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(1000, false);
        ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask callableTask3 = new ExecutorServiceFutureAndAwaitTermincationExample.CallableTask(3000, false);

        System.out.println("### Starting submitting tasks");

        // submit the callable and register the returned future object so that it can be processed later.
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask1));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask2));
        futuresList.add(executorService.submit(callableTask3));

        executorService.shutdown();

        System.out.println("### Finished submitting tasks and shutdown executorService");

        for (int i = 0; i < futuresList.size(); i++) {
            // here "get()" waits for the future tasks to be returned.
            System.out.println(futuresList.get(i).get());
        }

        System.out.println("### Finished.");
    }

    static class CallableTask implements Callable<String>{

        private long timeToSleep;
        private boolean shouldLog;

        CallableTask(long _timeToSleep, boolean _shouldLog){
            this.timeToSleep = _timeToSleep;
            this.shouldLog = _shouldLog;
        }

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            String str = new Date() + ": Processing - " + this.hashCode() + " | " + Thread.currentThread() + ", slept for seconds - " + timeToSleep; 
            System.out.println(str);
            Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
            if(this.shouldLog){
                System.out.println(str + " ||||| completed at: " + new Date());
            }
            return str + " ||||| completed at: " + new Date();
        }

    }
}
```

And for your point:

> I do not want the threads to keep running indefinitely, and also each
>   Future's exception should not affect other thread's Future.

`ExecutorService.awaitTermination` and `Future.get(<TimeOut>)` are not meant to control whether threads (which are processing your tasks) will run indefinitely or not, threads will run until the task they are performing is finished and `run` method of the thread is finished to completion. And I have explained the purpose of `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` and `Future.get(<TimeOut>)` above. And typically exception in one thread will not affect another thread, unless you are doing something which interrupt/affects other threads.

Comment: "usability" is probably not a term you want to use here.

Comment: @pvg Can you please elaborate, why, because OP's whole point is about this, please refer his question and his usage of term "*using*"

Comment: Sure, it's just not what 'usability' means. If two things have a different purpose, they don't have different 'usability'.  Usability is an orthogonal property. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability

Comment: @pvg Lets not get into literature buddy and keep it technical, point is OP should get what he is looking for.

Comment: We're not getting into literature 'buddy', you're just using a word that means something completely different from what you thought it meant. It's fine you misunderstood what it meant, but that's hardly a reason to get all snippy with me. Just change it to something that makes sense.

Comment: @pvg I don't know where you felt that I was being "snippy" with you, anyways I never enjoy getting myself engaged in these kind of trivial discussions so this is hard stop from my end for this discussion; as long as OP is getting the point I am fine, and if OP has any question/concern then I would be happy to address it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me what is the difference between using ExecutorService.awaitTermination vs using the Future.get() ?

`ExecutorService.awaitTermination()` should only be called after an `ExecutorService.shutdown()` request.  The spec doesn't define behavior if awaitTermination is called before shutdown.  But in a nutshell, awaitTermination should only be used if you are intending to throw away the ExecutorService and never use it again.  The Java EE Concurrency spec actually *rejects* applications calling this method.  Overall, this doesn't look like the right option for your use case.

`Future.get(Timeout)` is for waiting for a specific `Future` to complete, and has nothing to do with wanting to shutdown the `ExecutorService` that the future is running in.

Also related, see this answer:
[How to check if all tasks running on ExecutorService are completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845405/how-to-check-if-all-tasks-running-on-executorservice-are-completed/33845730#33845730)

Answer (score 0):

`Futire.get` waits for task to complete. `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` waits for executor service to be stopped. Usually, you should create `Executor` once and reuse it until application shutdown.

You may want to use `Fuitire.get` with timeout then cancel a future, if task was not completed. In this case other tasks will not be affected:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        Future task = executor.submit(() -> {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                return "1";
        });

        // later in time...
        try {
            Object result = task.get(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Task interrupted");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Task execution failed");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Task timed-out. isDone=" + task.isDone() + ", isCancelled=" + task.isCancelled());
            // cancel long-running task if you want to save resources
            task.cancel(true);
            System.out.println("Task Cancelled. isDone=" + task.isDone() + ", isCancelled=" + task.isCancelled());
        }

        // no more need for executor
        System.out.println("Shutting down executor");
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Task timed-out. isDone=false, isCancelled=false
Task Cancelled. isDone=true, isCancelled=true
Shutting down executor
```