# Indefinite task in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have the following variables:

```
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private Task<Boolean> worker;
```

I have a task that should be performed in another thread and the state of which should be monitored:

```
    public Worker<Boolean> updateTemplateBuffer() {
    worker = new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
               //task code
    };
    executor.execute(worker);
    return worker; 
}
```

The task is executed correctly, but I can’t track whether the task has ended or not.

Methods `executor.isTerminated()` and `executor.isShutdown()` always `false` anytime of a call. 
Tell me how to track the state of the task correctly (started or completed), because I had never encountered multi-threaded programming before.

Comment: executor.isTerminated / isShutdown is for the executor not for your task --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isTerminated() . Unless you have called the executor.shutdown they will return false

Comment: I would also suggest to look at this stackflow answer --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845405/how-to-check-if-all-tasks-running-on-executorservice-are-completed

Comment: Have a look on [Worker.stateProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#stateProperty--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) implements the [`Worker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) interface which has the [`state`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#stateProperty) property. You can listen to this property and react when the [`Worker.State`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.State.html) changes to `SUCCEEDED`, `CANCELLED`, or `FAILED`.

```
Task<Boolean> task = ...;
task.stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    // Test newVal and do something as needed...
});
```

Or you could listen to the [`running`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#runningProperty) property.

```
task.runningProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (!newVal) {
        // Do something...
    }
});
```

You can also listen for [`WorkerStateEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/WorkerStateEvent.html)s on the `Task`.

```
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {});
task.setOnCancelled(event -> {});
task.setOnFailed(event -> {});

// or even something like
task.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.ANY, event -> {
    // Test event type and do something as needed...
});
```

Then there's also the protected "state methods".

```
Task<Boolean> task = new Task<>() {

    @Override
    protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
        return false;
    }

    @Override protected void succeeded() {}
    @Override protected void cancelled() {}
    @Override protected void failed() {}

});
```

All these options will notify you on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have a volatile flag `completed` in your `Task` and set to `true` once the all the logic is executed.

```
class Task implements Callable<Boolean>{
    private volatile boolean completed = false;
    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        //task code
        completed = true;
    }
    public boolean isCompleted(){
        return this.completed;
    }
}
```

The methods `executor.isTerminated(`) and `executor.isShutdown()` always returns `false` as you did not shutdown the executor and cannot be used to check the status of individual tasks. These methods will tell you the state of the executor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it really impossible to find out the status of the task without introducing additional flags?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the Callable interface in the Task Class. And pass the Task to the executorService.Submit(Task); which will return a Future instance. Call future.get() which will wait until the Call block has completed execution