# javafx get result from thread with callable

Tags: java, javafx, java-threads, jfoenix

I have a javafx app, and I want to surround some code with "waiting" feature. So my code can be Runnable and Callable. The problem is getting result from Callabe. I tried to play with:

- wait()/notify()
- Platform.runLater
- creating daemon threads by hands
- Service

after reading some articles here, but it doesn't help.

How I want to call it:

```
            final String a =
                    CommonHelper.showWaiting(() -> {
                             System.out.println("test");
                             return "test2";  
                    });
```

That's how I work with Runnable:

```
public static void showWaiting(Runnable runnable) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            executorService.submit(new WaitingTask<>(executorService.submit(runnable)));
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

And my WaitingTask is:

```
public class WaitingTask<T> extends Task<Void> {
    @Getter
    private final Future<T> future;

    public WaitingTask(Future<T> future) {
        this.future = future;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() {
            showSpinner();
            while (true) {
                if (future.isDone()) {
                    hideSpinner();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

That works awesome - my app shows waiting spinner, and task runns in separate thread.

So I try to work the same way with Callable to get the result:

```
public static <T> T showWaiting(Callable<T> callable) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        try {
            FutureTask<T> task = new FutureTask<>(callable);
            Future<T> result = (Future<T>) executorService.submit(task);
            executorService.submit(new WaitingTask<>(result));
            return result.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

but I can not see waiting spinner, maybe the app's main thread waits for `result.get();` and the app freezes. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can't retrieve the result directly in the JavaFX Thread without freezing. You have to work with callbacks (or something similar)

Comment: The issue is that FutureTask#get is a blocking method.  You're starting the Callable on the executorService/thread but then you're blocking the main thread with the `result.get()` call.

Comment: @kendavidson yes I realized it (in the last paragraph), ideas to fix?))

Comment: Oh wow, sorry! It's been a morning.  The way you're doing it, you would need to implement the same `while(true) { if future.isDone() { ... } }` logic in your showWaiting method, that you have in your WaitingTask.   I think you're going a little overboard though, as you can just use one task, with a Spinners properties bound to the tasks properties.

Comment: @kendavidson thnx, but it's still the same

Comment: Sorry, I should have added, you need to be doing that in yet another thread. Since if you're doing it right in the method (just replacing result.get()) then you're effectively doing the same blocking. Is there any reason you can't use the task to do this, as it takes care of the correct threading for you using the appropriate callbacks?

Comment: I just don't understand how to do this(( I can use tasks and callbacks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193530/discussion-between-kendavidson-and-jesa).

Comment: You should be using a [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) if you want to compute something on a background thread and get the result on the FX thread.

Comment: @Slaw thnx, I already use it, you can see it in the code above

Comment: I actually missed that, but you aren't using it correctly. I added an answer.

Comment: @kendavidson thanks for your help, I've posted the solution below

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you are doing incorrectly:

---

1. You wrap your `Callable` in a `FutureTask` before submitting it to an `ExecutorService`. You don't need to do this, and in fact you shouldn't do this. Instead, just submit your `Callable` directly and you will get a `Future` in return.

   ```
   Future<T> future = executor.submit(callable);
   ```

   If you're using the core implementation of `ExecutorService` the returned `Future` *will be* a `FutureTask` anyway. Not that you should care—the only important thing is that its a `Future`. Note the same goes for `Runnable`s; just submit them directly, don't wrap them in a `FutureTask` first.

---

2. You're submitting your `Callable`, getting a `Future`, and wrapping said `Future` in a `Task`...and then submitting your `Task`. This means you will have *two* tasks for every one you want to execute. Depending on how your `ExecutorService` is configured, this equates to using *two threads* per task.

   You should be using your `Task` as if it was your `Callable`. Do the work inside the `Task#call()` method and return the result. Then only submit the `Task`, don't wrap it in anything first.

   ```
   executor.execute(task); // Don't need the Future here, just use "execute"
   ```

   If you want the result of the `Task` you can register *callbacks* (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54233712/6395627)). The class is designed to invoke these callbacks on the *JavaFX Application Thread*.

   ```
   task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
       T value = task.getValue();
       // do something with value...
   });
   ```

   Note that `Task` extends `FutureTask`. This seems contradictory to point 1, but that's just how it is. Personally, I wouldn't have designed the class that way—it ends up wrapping the `Task` in another `Future` (likely `FutureTask`) when executed using the *Executor Framework*.

---

3. This is related to number 2; if you fix that issue then this issue inherently goes away.

   You are spin waiting for the wrapped `Future` to complete. This is a waste of resources. The `Future` interface has a `get()` method that will block the calling thread until said `Future` is done. If the `Future` completes normally you'll get the value in return, else if it completes exceptionally an `ExecutionException` will be thrown. The third option is the calling thread is interrupted and an `InterruptedException` is thrown.

---

4. If the method names "`showSpinner`" and "`hideSpinner`" aren't misleading, you are updating the UI from a background thread. **Never** update the UI from a thread other than the *JavaFX Application Thread*. Now, you *could* wrap those calls in a `Platform.runLater` action, but you could also use the properties/callbacks of the `Task`. For instance, you could listen to the `running` property to know when to show and hide your spinner.

---

Taking all that into account, your example should look more like:

```
// Doesn't have to be an anonymous class
Task<String> task = new Task<>() {

    @Override 
    protected String call() {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "test2";
    }

});
task.runningProperty().addListener((obs, wasRunning, isRunning) -> {
    if (isRunning) {
        showSpinner();
    } else {
        hideSpinner();
    }
});
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    String a = task.getValue();
    // Do something with value.
});

executorService.execute(task);
```

For more information, I suggest reading:

- [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)
- Documentation of [`javafx.concurrent.Worker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html)
- Documentation of [`javafx.concurrent.Task`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) (and `Worker`'s other implementations)
- Possibly a tutorial on Java's *Executor Framework*.

Comment: Thanks!
About p.2 - I can't make something like
`task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                final T value = task.getValue();
                return value;
            });`
and that's what I really need

Comment: The `Worker` interface and its implementations are meant to do work on a background thread while reporting information, including the value, back to the _JavaFX Application Thread_. You never want to block the FX thread waiting for a result—your application will become unresponsive. If you need to do something after the task has succeeded, execute that code in the `onSucceeded` handler. That said, _if you're on a background thread and want to wait for the task's result_, you can use `Task#get` (remember, `Task` extends `FutureTask`). But then why use a `Task` in the first place?

Comment: yes, I just want to use `Task#get`, but that "freezes" the app, and that's ok. I just want user seeing the spinner while waiting, not the unresponsive app (that can cause some panick)

Comment: I'm confused. You say, "_that 'freezes' the app, and that's ok_", but then follow that up with, "_want user seeing the spinner while waiting, not the unresponsive app_". An unresponsive app **is** a frozen app. If you don't want the UI to be frozen, you **cannot** call `Task#get`—or any other blocking call—on the FX thread. Why do you need to wait for the result in the first place? Why not just do whatever needs to be done in the callback?

Comment: I'll try to explain:
I want to have a wrapper for "heavy" processes
For example, let's take database stuff
First is runnable - update 100500 rows ignoring result

So I can call in code:
`CommonHelper.showWaiting(() -> getDao().updateAllRows());`

Second is callable - get 100500 rows 
So I can call in code:
`List<Person> result = CommonHelper.showWaiting(() -> getDao().getAllPersons());`

Comment: Maybe you are confused because I can't describe normally in  english, sorry:(
I want to say that for user (UI) there is a defference: 
he sees a spinner(and all is OK) or he sees an unresponsive app while waiting

Comment: If the FX thread is blocked waiting for `Task#get` the **spinner will be frozen**. The FX thread is responsible for updating UI state and scheduling the next frame render. If it is stuck in some blocking call _none of that can happen_. The whole point of using concurrency in a GUI application is to avoid such a situation. Blocking until the background task finishes completely negates the benefits of using a separate thread in this context. When it comes to concurrency and GUI applications you need design your code using callbacks; when a task finishes, it _notifies_ you—you don't wait for it.

Comment: thanks for your help, I've posted the solution below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for help, especially @Slaw and @kendavidson
Finally I've found a simple and perfect solution here:
[Modal JaxaFX Progress Indicator running in Background](https://www.rational-pi.be/2016/05/modal-jaxafx-progress-indicator-running-in-background/)

Maybe I'll post my full generic-based example here, based on this principles